# Paste to Google Sheet using VBA & Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, google-sheets, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to share a particular range in an Excel Spreadsheet to a Google Sheet.  I am using the Selenium reference and have made it as far as getting to the Edit Menu in the Google Sheet, but I cannot figure out how to complete the final step of pasting.

```
Sub UpdateGoogle()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11qzYnGz17q19G8-GrTGszUEuVkBr69ZtEy55VrbM2Zw/edit#gid=0"
    bot.Get "/"
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DASHBOARD")
    unusedrow = Columns("f:n").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    printrangefordashboard = "f2:n" & unusedrow
Set rng = Sht.Range(printrangefordashboard)
    rng.Copy
    bot.FindElementById("docs-edit-menu").Click
    Stop
End Sub
```

I've tried SendKeys and that doesn't work.  Also, I don't understand why I am getting a chrome browser that doesn't allow pasting when I run this.